# Python "requests" module file upload - determining "content type" field automatically based on file extension?

Tags: python, python-requests, mime

I am trying to upload many files using the "requests" module in Python and I'm wondering if there's a way to detect "content type" automatically based on file extension (since there are many different MIME types that I am trying to upload).

If I leave the content type as blank, the files just upload as "text" files.

My code looks something like this:

```
import os
import requests

folder_path = myfolderpath
folder_files_list = os.listdir(folder_path)

import os
import requests

folder_path = myfolderpath

folder_files_list = os.listdir(folder_path)

for i in folder_files_list:
    file_location = folder_path + '/' + i
    file_name_cut, file_extension = os.path.splitext(i)
    files = [ ('File' (i, open(file_location, 'rb'), 'application/pdf')) ]
    data = { 'name' : i }
    url = 'myurl'
    headers = { myheaders }
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files, data=data)
```

and I'm trying to replace the "application/pdf" part with whatever content type is needed. Is there any way to do this using "file_extension" ? (To be more specific, the files can be pdf, txt, docx, xlsx, but I am wondering if it's possible to add something that gets a content type no matter what the file type is) Thank you so much.

Comment: Something like the `mimetypes` module might help? https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in folder_files_list:
    file_location = folder_path + '/' + i
    extension = os.path.splitext(file_location)[-1]
    # may need to add this line too:
    # extension = extension.replace('.', '')
    file_name_cut, file_extension = os.path.splitext(i)
    files = [ ('File' (i, open(file_location, 'rb'), extension)) ]
    data = { 'name' : i }
    url = 'myurl'
    headers = { myheaders }
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files, data=data)
```

Will this work? If you extract extension from your file and insert it in a place where `application/pdf` was? or you can put `f'application/{extension}'`,  depends on how content need to be specified.